# DeqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier overlapping two cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the `UITableViewDataSource` method, I check to see if I have data:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (data.count == 0)
    {
       return 1; //This one cell will be of type NoDataTypeCell
    } else {
       return data.count //These cells will be of type DataTypeCell
    }
}
```

so at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I check for which type of cells to use, in the same way:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell* dataCell = (SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hasDataIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (data.count == 0)
    {
        NODataTypeCell* cellNoData = (NODataTypeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"noDataIdentifier];
        //Setup the noDataCell
        return cellNoData;

    } else {
        return dataCell;
    }
}
```

This results in something I've never seen before. As expected my controller loads with data being empty. As a result, 1 NODataTypeCell is dequeued.

Once the data comes in, TableView is reloaded.

`numberOfRowsInSection` returns `data.count`

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` does NOT return `noDataCell`, it returns `data.count` amount of `dataCells`

Except my tableView still has a noDataCell. Weirdest part? its directly over the first cell in the tableView. The Cell is unselectable, and also makes the cell behind it unselectable. It has no data, as it has not been setup. But its there, and it won't go away.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a picture of the view debugger perspective behind the cells. You can clearly see that there are two cells are the first row, and only one cell on the second row
[image]

Comment: Have you tried shifting the dequeue of SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell to the else clause? Because even though you aren't returning the dataCell to be rendered, it seems as though the dequeue process doesn't handle dequeuing more the once well.

Comment: @CStreel This is the error thrown when I do as you suggested: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITableViewReorderingSupport _needsSetup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x148b4b6d0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will return an object `cell` and add to `tableView`.

In your code above:

```
 SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell* dataCell = (SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hasDataIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (data.count == 0)
{
    NODataTypeCell* cellNoData = (NODataTypeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"noDataIdentifier];
```

In case `data = 0`. Two cell already add to same indexpath of `tableView`. So it's reason for bug.

You should separate your code to return exact one cell in indexPath like:

```
if (data.count == 0)
{
    NODataTypeCell* cellNoData = (NODataTypeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"noDataIdentifier];
    //Setup the noDataCell
    return cellNoData;

} else {
    SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell* dataCell = (SAFindSuggestedTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hasDataIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return dataCell;
}
```

I see that you comment about crash. I think it's because your logic with your real code.

Comment: Yep you got it. Issue with the logic, this is what needed to happen